# Facing issue while getting the Json "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Below is my area

[image]

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Get_JSon()
{
    List<AdminModule> mod = new List<AdminModule>();
    mod.Add(new AdminModule { MyName = "1" });
    mod.Add(new AdminModule { MyName = "2" });
    mod.Add(new AdminModule { MyName = "3" });

    return Json(mod);
}
```

**Model**

```
public class AdminModule
{
    [Required]
    public String MyName { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model _1.Areas.Admin.Models.AdminModule
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
}
<div id="formContainer_Json" style="display:none" 
      data-url="@Url.Action("Get_JSon", "Admin", new { area = "Admin" })">
</div>
<input id="BTN_Json" onclick="return GetJsonR()" type="button" value="Button" />
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" 
             src="@Url.Content("~/areas/admin/scripts/myscript.js")"></script>
}
```

**Scripts**

```
function GetJsonR() {
    var $formContainer = $('#formContainer_Json');
    var url = $formContainer.attr('data-url');
    $.get(url, null, function (data) { return false; });
    return false;
}
```

Confusion is - When submitting the button to get Json result 
**500 Internal Server Error**

Also in the title it is showing below info...

```
<title>This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be 
disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To 
allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.</title>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the below line...

```
return Json(mod);
```

with below...

```
return Json(mod, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```